# How to access WordPress logged in username via C# HttpModule

Tags: c#, wordpress, httpmodule

I have a simple HttpModule that I want to use to control access to certain content on my WordPress site.  Some details are available at [How to restrict access to WordPress content in .NET/PHP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382418/how-to-restrict-access-to-wordpress-content-in-net-php-application/).

To do this I need to be able to determine the username associated with any request.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the details at http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx I wrote a simple method that gets the WP login cookie from the incoming request.  The basic outline is given by:

```
private static String GetWpLoginCookie(HttpContext context)
{
    String[] cookieKeys = context.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
    foreach (var cookieKey in cookieKeys)
    {
        if (cookieKey.StartsWith("wordpress_logged_in"))
        {
            return WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Cookies[cookieKey].Value);
        }
    }
    return "Not found";
}
```

I can now get the username by from loginCookie.Split('|')[0].